# SQL: What is difference between "where FIRSTNAME = 'X' and rownum <5" AND "where rownum <5 and FIRSTNAME = 'X'"?

Tags: sql, oracle, rownum

What is difference between rownum on extreme right and rownum on second right of sql query? or you can say difference if we swap rownum

```
select * from EMPLOYEE where FIRSTNAME = 'X' and rownum <5; 
// Taking Less Time compare to next one in oracle

select * from EMPLOYEE where  rownum <5 and FIRSTNAME = 'X';
```

The result is same but what difference technically it has.

PS: I am being interviewed by guy on same but he seems unsatisfied. I only could reply that execution of extreme right is first.

Comment: I can't believe it would matter where in the `where` a condition is. Have you checked the execution plans? And are you seeing this behaviour in both Oracle and mysql?

Comment: Normally there should be no difference. Are you sure the difference is not caused by the fact, that the one query is cached and the other is not?

Comment: @HoneyBadger: I have seen this behavior in Oracle only. Don't have mysql as of now :(

Comment: I would also consider which of the fields have indexes and whether there is any partitionining on either of them.

Comment: There is absolutely no difference. Look at the execution plan and you will see.

Comment: "*I only could reply that execution of extreme right is first*" - that is plain wrong.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name:  I have heard that sql is calculated from right to left? Is it only true for compilation but not execution????

Comment: Then you have heard incorrectly. There is no defined order in the evaluation of the conditions. And SQL isn't actually compiled.

Comment: join/coalesce/case are evaluated from left to right - _logically_. Actual execution order may be whatever the SQL optimizer finds best.

Answer (score 7):

[TL;DR] There is no difference in the `EXPLAIN PLAN` for the two queries; they are evaluated identically.

---

**Test Data**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE employee ( firstname ) AS
SELECT CHR( 64 + level ) FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 26;
```

**Explain Plans**:

```sql
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR
select * from EMPLOYEE where FIRSTNAME = 'X' and rownum <5;

SELECT PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY());
```

outputs:

> ```
> | PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT                                                               |
> | :------------------------------------------------------------------------------ |
> | Plan hash value: 3463100252                                                     |
> |                                                                                 |
> | ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | | Id  | Operation          | Name     | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | |
> | ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |          |     1 |     4 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 | |
> | |*  1 |  COUNT STOPKEY     |          |       |       |            |          | |
> | |*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| EMPLOYEE |     1 |     4 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 | |
> | ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> |                                                                                 |
> | Predicate Information (identified by operation id):                             |
> | ---------------------------------------------------                             |
> |                                                                                 |
> |    1 - filter(ROWNUM<5)                                                         |
> |    2 - filter("FIRSTNAME"='X')                                                  |
> |                                                                                 |
> | Note                                                                            |
> | -----                                                                           |
> |    - dynamic sampling used for this statement (level=2)                         |
> ```

and

```sql
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR
select * from EMPLOYEE where rownum <5 and FIRSTNAME = 'X';

SELECT PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY());
```

outputs:

> ```
> | PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT                                                               |
> | :------------------------------------------------------------------------------ |
> | Plan hash value: 3463100252                                                     |
> |                                                                                 |
> | ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | | Id  | Operation          | Name     | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | |
> | ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |          |     1 |     4 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 | |
> | |*  1 |  COUNT STOPKEY     |          |       |       |            |          | |
> | |*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| EMPLOYEE |     1 |     4 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 | |
> | ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> |                                                                                 |
> | Predicate Information (identified by operation id):                             |
> | ---------------------------------------------------                             |
> |                                                                                 |
> |    1 - filter(ROWNUM<5)                                                         |
> |    2 - filter("FIRSTNAME"='X')                                                  |
> |                                                                                 |
> | Note                                                                            |
> | -----                                                                           |
> |    - dynamic sampling used for this statement (level=2)                         |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9590267eba4374d8c5d0915a60429acb)*

As you can see Oracle's SQL engine generates identical plans for both queries and will evaluate them identically; there is no difference from the order of the expressions in the `WHERE` clause.